# Hiw do I get the dome off of ceiling fan?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

How do I get this dome off to change the light bulbs? I've tried pulling the brackets, but nothing budges. The dome doesn't screw on/off either. Any help would be greatly appreciated! [image][image][image][image]

Comment: Do you have a manufacturer or model?

Comment: Is it a user replaceable lamp? LED? And model/manufacturer would help.

Comment: It looks from the pictures like the glass is held on by three brass wings.  See if those are hinged and swing out to free the glass.

Comment: Like @fixer1234 wrote - looks like the wings are what hold the dome.  Can one or more of the wings slide in the direction that exposes more of the dome?

Comment: I can not move the wings.  I thought the same thing, but they don't swing out of down. I've used some force, but not a huge amount as I'm afraid to pull the whole thing down.  Thank you for responding!